# Ionic Cordova native touch sound

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am newbie in hybrid app development using ionic 1 with angularJs. 
I have deployed the app to my samsung device (android). I found out that when I touch any elements (eg: button) it doesn't have any sounds effect.

How to enable the touch sound like the native app?

I also visited this article http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-add-sound-effects-to-your-ionic-app-with-native-audio/ , but this is not I want to achieve. It teach on how to enable and load audio in the app. However, I want to have the native touch sound of the phone

I apologize if this similar question exist in somewhere else, I have searched through a lot of sites and I couldn't find an answer

I also tried https://github.com/MatiMenich/cordova-plugin-nativeClickSound and no luck.. Please find the code below for my index.html and controller.js

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script> 

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script> 

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('SoundController', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $timeout){
    var clickyClasses = ['sound-click', 'button']; 
    nativeclick.watch(clickyClasses);
    $scope.click = function() {
      nativeclick.trigger();
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/MatiMenich/cordova-plugin-nativeClickSound. It's  under MIT License. Hope it'll help you

This will applied native sound to all button and an "a" tag with href when clicking it.

```
var clickyClasses = ['button', 'a']; 
nativeclick.watch(clickyClasses);
```

Comment: Hi digit, I have installed the plugin. I have tried the same in my controller but it return error "nativeclick" is not defined

Comment: Hi, most ngCordova plugins will not work in a web browser because they use native device code. Try it on the emulator or real device instead

Comment: This is my controller code.. do i have to add any parameter to the function?

.controller('SoundController', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $timeout){
 var clickyClasses = ['sound-click', 'button']; 
 nativeclick.watch(clickyClasses);
 
 $scope.click = function() {
   nativeclick.trigger();
 };
});

Comment: no, you dont need to inject anything in the controller. Did you try run it on the real device? android or ios?

Comment: I tried to run it in android, and it got the same error nativeclick is not defined. Do i missed anything?

Comment: ok. try this instead <!-- In the view -->
<button ng-click="click()"></button>
// In the controller
$scope.click = function() {
  nativeclick.trigger();
};

Comment: Try use it on ng-click.

Comment: Hi digit, my question is updated. I have tried your propose solution and still the same error return nativeclick is not defined

Comment: Thanks digit!!!!!!!! I have been looking solution for 2 days... 
where can i find "nativeclick" function definition actually?
is it cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound folder under plugins folder?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that it help you out. The documentation is too useless, need to figure it out for the solution.

Comment: It's in www folder. The file called nativeclick.js.

Comment: i can't find it under www folder. what actually happen after i run the cmd --> "ionic run android"
is it the nativeclick.js will be complied in somewhere?

Comment: hehe.. Sorry, its under plugins, you're correct. Check in the www folder under native click plugin folder

Comment: did you try the plugin too? when i click the button, the sounds is not that "native" , the "tap" sound is like repeated twice in the same time

Comment: I'm not try it yet. Maybe in the future. I think maybe the button redundancy issue.  Though, i think it is  a great plugin . Also it added for ios compatibility too. Not too many plugin out there unless you're going to have an effort to create plugin for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

install plugin 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound'

use this code in app.js

```
.controller('MyController',function($scope,
$cordovaNativeAudio) {   

    $scope.sound = function() {
            nativeclick.trigger();
     };
});
```

you can use sound() function where ever you want native sound, for example button

```
<button ng-click="sound()">native sound</button>
```

test it in device, web browser through error.